# connection to MSN messanger in android

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, msn-messenger

I tried connecting to MSN messanger using Smack library with follwiing code

```
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;

ConnectionConfiguration configuration = new
ConnectionConfiguration("messenger.hotmail.com", 1863, "hotmail.com"); 

configuration.setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.disabled);
configuration.setCompressionEnabled(false);

XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(configuration);

try 
{
    connection.connect();
}
catch (XMPPException e) 
{
    Log.e(TAG, "MSN connect Failed !!");
}
```

I am getting " connection failed, no response from the server"

I also tried using java msn library it is also not working.

I also tried using TJMSN library , but my application is crashing with Verify error :

Please help me in this...by suggestiing any method to connect to **msn messanger in android**

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Messenger doesn't use XMPP, so you can't connect to it using an XMPP client (which is what you're trying to do)

Comment: do u know how to connect to Microsoft messenger ?

Answer (score 1):

> Microsoft Messenger doesn't use XMPP

Looks like it's no longer the case. Take a look at the following post **"[Anyone can build a Messenger client—with open standards access via XMPP](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_live/b/windowslive/archive/2011/12/14/anyone-can-build-a-windows-live-messenger-client-with-open-standards-access-via-xmpp.aspx)"**.

The article provides links to development documentation and **[Smack based Android code samples](https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK/blob/master/Samples/XMPP-Samples/Android/src/com/ms/wlm/XmppClient.java)** as well:

*"Developers interested in learning more about our XMPP interface can check out **[our code samples on GitHub](https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK/tree/master/Samples/XMPP-Samples)** along with **[the overview documentation on the Live Connect developer center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowslive/hh561460)**. These should give you enough information to get started building integration with the Messenger network into your mobile apps, devices and web sites."*